# How to create a master layout in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins, widget

Lately I have been working with Wordpress and I created a home page layout that I need to adapt to all pages. 
Now I have been duplicating pages to make all pages look like the home page. Whenever I need to change a small thing I need to do this for all pages. I work with WPBakery Page builder that allows me to create a template but this does not work the way I want. I realized if I make the content as a widget that I can just change that but then I have to make a widget for every small piece of content. I was wondering if there is a different approach to this.

Comment: Can you try with making template file for your requirement?

Comment: I tried to do that but I can't edit the template so if I have a small change I need to readd the template to every page again.

Comment: template file we create for that we don't need to go every small changes in all the file. then why this happen to you? once you select template every page changes of template file reflect to every page.

Comment: When I read the docs: https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/learning-more/templates/ it does not say anything about editing only when I purchase the addon which I am considering right now but I would like more info before purchasing it.

Comment: I am taking about theme template out of this plugin(WPBakery).

Comment: I am not sure how to do this I have no template options.

Comment: for that you need to learn create custom template in theme and use it.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that.